# How to vectorize pandas code with helper function and pass whole row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a helper function right now that I was using with `itertuples` on my pandas dataframe. I have 50+ columns and am using them all in my process_row function and don't want to pass them 1 by 1.

Ex:

```
def process_row(self, df_row):
   return df_row['sky_color'] == 'blue':
```

I have sped it up with apply doing:

```
df['isSkyBlueExample'] = df.apply(process_row, axis = 1)
```

How can I properly apply pandas or numpy vectorization and speed up my apply even more? My DF has 50+ columns that I use in the logic, and it is much easier to pass in the whole row to the helper function instead of 50 params, and every example I have found refers to specific DF columns which will work if I break it out.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"sky_color": ["blue", "red", "blue", "green"]})
>>> df["isSkyBlueExample"] = df["sky_color"] == "blue"
>>> df
  sky_color  isSkyBlueExample
0      blue              True
1       red             False
2      blue              True
3     green             False
```

The expression `df["sky_color"] == "blue"` returns a boolean `Series` that can be used directly to create your new column.

Comment: This would work if I am using just 1 param, however I am using 30-50 params to calculate the exact value for that column.

Comment: @LanceBloom Sorry, I misunderstood the question. How are you using the column values? Is it a calculation or do you have additional logic involved?

Comment: It is a calculation, I generally use at least 20 of them and feel if I rewrite the program to pass in 20 variables it will get a lot messier + error prone + rewriting a lot of code. Would be a lot simpler to somehow pass in the row?

Comment: @LanceBloom Are you able to include the body of your `process_row` function in your question? If it truly is just a calculation then I would do your calculations directly with the `DataFrame`, using intermediate variables as needed to make it readable.